# Angular Typescript filtering object array not working

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to filter an array of objects based on value. Of the following console.log, only the first on is giving the expected result:

```
console.log('log1: ', sf);
console.log('log2: ', sf.filter(f => true));
console.log('log3: ', sf.filter(f => f.Specification.FormSelector === 'app-g-form'));
console.log('log4: ', sf.findIndex(f => f.Specification.FormSelector.includes('app-g-form')));
```

The results of the above is:

[image]

For log2, log3 and log4 I was expecting the console output to be the same as that for log1. The output log1 shows that sf does contain valid data.

Comment: That is a little peculiar, at least if `sf` is a legitimate array. Where did `sf` come from?

Comment: Can you recreate in a stackblitz? This is my version which works as expected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfkcrc

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The problem must be in between the calls. Do you perform any other actions that cause a side-effect on `sf` and therefore the logs print out the results?

Comment: Like @PhilippMeissner asked, do you modify the object `sf` in anyway after you log it? Late modifications can still be reflected in the logs. Console log doesn't hold a copy of the object, it contains only a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

I may have got this working.  I was setting parts of the array with:

```
const sf1: GSubForm = {Specification: this.detailSpecification};
this.specification.SubForms.push(sf1);
```

The above code was placed an observable I was using to get data from an API.  After setting the data, I set the SubForms array.  After moving the code out of the observable and placing directly in ngOnInit(){} everything is working.

Not sure why one way works and not the other, but I'm happy it is moving forward.

[image]